# Hiding a button on clicking it in fragment for always with shared preferences

Tags: java, android, fragment

I want yo hide a button which is in fragment XML, by clicking on it , for always it will be hidden till uninstalling the app, by shared preferences. But I am getting errors , 'Unknown method setVisibility of android.widget.button' and   'btnsearch variable must be final to be used in  local class'  . here is my code:

```
package com.niezwm.bododictionary.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import com.niezwm.bododictionary.R;


public class SearchFragment extends Fragment{

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
Button btnsearch;



public SearchFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
 }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View   onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container,false);
Button btnsearch =(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref",0);
btnsearch.setVisiblity(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("visiblity",false));
      btnsearch.setOnClickListener(new   View.OnClickListener(){
@Override 
public void onClick(View view){
if(
                        btnsearch.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE){
      btnsearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();  
                    editor.putBoolean("visiblity",true)
                        .commit();
                        }
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
// end onClick
});
return rootView;
}
// end onCreateView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you access those two variables in the anonymous inner class you have to make them final:

```
final Button btnsearch = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnsearch);
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
```

**EDIT**

`setVisibility()` wants an int, not a boolean.

```
boolean visibility = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("visiblity", false);
btnsearch.setVisibility(visibility ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Comment: setVisibility wants an int as input, not a boolean. You set the visibility based on the boolean you get from sharedPreferences.

Comment: Can you please edit my code add your corrections , thanks .

Comment: I already did, for the parts that are relevant, look at the edit in the post please.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for help , I will try it

Comment: Thanks, but I got a problem again, if I use this for different fragments in a tab layout , suppose I have 3 fragments in a tab layout . and I used this set visibility for all three with different id's, when I click on fragment 1 's button then it's button will hide also fragment 2 and 3 's also automatically hiding

Comment: This is because you just set one boolean for all the fragments! I suggest to set a value for each fragment. The value could be an id to identify the fragment or also an int with the position of the fragment.

Comment: So now I have to change this:    boolean visibility = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("visiblity", false); to boolean visibility2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("visiblity", false);   ...?